# What's wrong with this simple .htaccess redirect instruction?

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.2

I have an .htaccess file in the root directory of my domain that contains only the following:

```
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 /showex.php /erase.php
```

The two files mentioned above exist and are in the root directory.  However, when I upload this .htaccess file to my root directory, the entire domain stops loading and instead I get the following message:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.

here's my .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler Extension_Type .html .htm .php3 .php4
Action Extension_Type /cgi-bin/php.dat
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
AddType 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'

Redirect 301 /showex.php mydomain.com/erase.php
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong (or perhaps missing) in my .htaccess file?

Comment: You probably have this error with another rule in your .htaccess file. can you show us your .htaccess?

Comment: Here is the complete htaccess fileAddHandler Extension_Type .html .htm .php3 .php4
Action Extension_Type /cgi-bin/php.dat
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html 
AddType 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' html
 
Redirect 301 /showex.php http://www.mydomain.com/erase.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your redirect rule in this way:

```
Redirect 301 /showex.php http://www.yourdomain.com/erase.php
```

Where obviously www.yourdomain.com has to be changed with your website. Check and let me know if it works.

Comment: I have access to a cgi-bin directory above the public directory. Don't know if that helps.

Comment: Here's what I just tried... AddHandler Extension_Type .html .htm .php3 .php4
Action Extension_Type /cgi-bin/php.dat
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html 
AddType 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' html
 
Redirect 301 /showex.php http://www.mydomain.com/erase.php

Comment: When I use your suggested redirect rule, the htaccess file no longer crashes my site -- however the page does not redirect either. (Sorry about the multiple comments but I'm not used to a comment form in which the "enter" button enters the comment on the first click as opposed to moving the cursor down the line to start a new paragraph.)

Comment: what is the full relative URL of /showex.php ? if it is /dir1/showex.php I think you've to include that too. (You can edit your comments for 5 minutes, there is an edit link).

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative URI.

> The new URL should be **an absolute URL** beginning with a scheme and hostname

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)